# Dynamic date selection based on current date in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My objective is to select the data within the dates of 25th of this month and 15th of next month

The query can happen any time between 25th of this month and 15th of next moth .

Whenever we run the query the filter should be mm/25/yyy and mm+1/15/yyyy

How can I achieve this

Comment: check out `dateadd()`

Comment: There are a number of [date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which will allow you to work out which month you are in and compute the start and end dates.

Comment: What if someone ran the report on the 20th of the month for some reason? Do you need to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

I did not realize that it is SQL server 2008. As per GMB suggestion, I modified the query and I assume it should support SQL server 2008.

```
Select * from tablea 
where date between    cast(convert(varchar(10), concat(year(getdate()),'-',month(getdate()), '-', '25'),110) as date) and   cast(convert(varchar(10), 
concat(year(dateadd(month, 1, getdate())),'-',month(dateadd(month, 1, getdate())), '-', '15'),110) as date) ;
```

These are the values you get from the where condition:

[image]

Comment: Presumably, OP wants ` dateadd(day, 16, eomonth (getdate()))` as an upper bound (which would actually produce the 15th of next month). Also, I am unsure that SQL Server 2008 does support `eomonth()` - you might want to provide an alternative solution in this case.